# QML application freezes on QApplication.exec() and does not show a window

Tags: python, python-3.x, qml

I've written simple script to check QML capabilities on python3 (before I used c++ for this):

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine
import sys
import logging


def run():
    logging.basicConfig(level = logging.DEBUG)
    logging.info("Create application object")
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    logging.info("Create qml engine/view")
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
    logging.info("Loading qml file")
    engine.load(('./qml/CurrentValues.qml'))
    if not engine.rootObjects():
        logging.fatal("Engine root objects in empty")
        return -1

    engine.quit.connect(app.quit)
    logging.info("Run application")
    return app.exec_()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(run())
```

On the line "return app.exec_()" the script freezes and doesn't show window. Script does not show errors and it is not stopped by Ctrl-C, only killed by kill command.

I have ubuntu 17.10 and installed packages: python3-pyqt5, python3-pyqt5.qtquick. I also tried to use pip version of this packages (PyQt5) and tried PySide2. I used QCoreApplication, QGuiApplication, but it did not give an effect. It does not work with any qml files.

What could be the problem?

CurrentValues.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import "."

ListView {
    orientation: ListView.Horizontal
    flickableDirection: Flickable.HorizontalFlick
    delegate: CurrentValueViewer {}
    model: ListModel {
        id: valuesModel
        ListElement {
            valueName: "Temp"
            curValue: "250°"
        }
        ListElement {
            valueName: "CO2"
            curValue: "125 PPM"
        }
        ListElement {
            valueName: "O2"
            curValue: "18 %"
        }
        ListElement {
            valueName: "N2"
            curValue: "15%"
        }
        ListElement {
            valueName: "RH"
            curValue: "80 %"
        }
    }
}
```

CurrentValueViewer.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

Rectangle {
    id: valueViewer
    width: 120
    height: 80
    color: "#d6d6d6"
    radius: 10

    Column {

        Text {
            id: name
            text: valueName
        }

        Text {
            id: value
            text: "<html><body>" + curValue +"<sup>°C</sup></body></html>"
            font.bold: true
            font.pointSize: 15
        }

        Text {
            id: moreInfo
            text: "And more..."
        }
    }
}
```

Working version on c++:

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>
#include "currentmeasurement.h"
#include "currentmeasurementsmodel.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QLatin1String("qrc:/CurrentValues.qml")));
    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
        return -1;

    CurrentMeasurementsModel measurementList;
    measurementList.append(CurrentMeasurement("Temp", 25, "°C"));
    measurementList.append(CurrentMeasurement("CO2", 125, "PPM"));
    measurementList.append(CurrentMeasurement("O2", 18, "%"));
    measurementList.append(CurrentMeasurement("N2", 75, "%"));
    measurementList.append(CurrentMeasurement("RH", 85, "%"));
    QQmlContext *ctxt = engine.rootContext();
    ctxt->setContextProperty("measurementModel", &measurementList);

    return app.exec();
}
```

It uses a class based on QAbstractListModel

Comment: show CurrentValues.qml

Comment: I have tested your code that shows with a suitable qml and I have not had problems.

Comment: Have you executed it from the terminal?

Comment: CurrentValues.qml:
```
```

Comment: Yes, i executed it from from terminal. File CurrentValues.qml is too long to add in the comment, I tried to execute this code with different QML files, it didn't work. If I don't use QML but use Qt widgets, it works fine.

Comment: do not put code in the comments, edit your question and add it there

Answer (score 0):

[`QQmlApplicationEngine`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlapplicationengine.html) can only display [`QQuickWindow`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickwindow.html), so the [`ListView`](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.9/qml-qtquick-listview.html) can not be displayed so a possible solution is to use [`ApplicationWindow`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-applicationwindow.html) as root.

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import "."

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    ListView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        orientation: ListView.Horizontal
        flickableDirection: Flickable.HorizontalFlick
        delegate: CurrentValueViewer {}
        model: ListModel {
            id: valuesModel
            ListElement {
                valueName: "Temp"
                curValue: "250°"
            }
            ListElement {
                valueName: "CO2"
                curValue: "125 PPM"
            }
            ListElement {
                valueName: "O2"
                curValue: "18 %"
            }
            ListElement {
                valueName: "N2"
                curValue: "15%"
            }
            ListElement {
                valueName: "RH"
                curValue: "80 %"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've added ApplicationWindow to QML file, but it does not work. Maybe  there are not enough installed packages in my system? I tried to run same qml code from c++, It worked